# Twig get field value from panel page

Tags: 8, panels

I am trying to get the value of a field that is displayed in a panel page. I might be going about this all wrong, because I'm still getting used to Drupal 8. I want to display book information, including the ISBN value, which I use to make a link to Amazon.

I first tried a node template: **node--book_page.html.twig** and was able to do it by inserting the value of `{{ content.field_isbn10.0 }}` into the URL I added to the twig. This worked great, but when I tried doing the same thing to the template that I set up to be used by the panel page, nothing happens.

I know I have the custom layout twig working as it should, but I'm guessing that there is more to requesting the value than `{{ content.field_isbn10.0 }}` now that it's going through node_view in Panels.

I have tried adding it to the panel page as **entity_field:node:field_isbn10** as well as **field_block:node:book_page:field_isbn10**. I just can't seem to get how to access the ISBN field value like I did in the node template.

Here's what shows using kint:
[image]

Here's the top of that knit:
[image]

Comment: This kint snippet looks like an entity field. So `{{ ?.?.?.field_isbn10.value }}` should work, if you add the three levels above the field not shown in the screenshot.

Comment: I can't see the field parents on that devel output, but as far I know it is done with `{{ content._row.entity.field_isbn10.value }}`. That should print out the field value.

Comment: I added the top of that knit column. I what was suggested, both with .value and .0 but neither worked. Here is the line I'm using to test it out with in my twig.
    {% if content.col_2|render|trim is not empty %} <div class="atl__lc lc-2"> {{ content.col_2 }} <p>Amazon: {{ content._row.entity.field_isbn10.0 }}</p></div>{% endif %}

Comment: Sorry. I can't seem to make code in my comment work

Comment: Did you try my code

Comment: Yes I did. My test is just a simple line: `<p>Amazon: {{ content._row.entity.field_isbn10.value }}</p>`.

Comment: The word "Amazon:" prints out but nothing else

Comment: In case you missed it I added the top of the knit to the question

Comment: The question title about a panel page is confusing, I assumed the node would be nested deeper. Now it looks you have a node template where you can access node fields directly `{{ node.field_isbn10.value }}`.

Comment: I added the top of the knit tree so it can be seen now. I'm trying to display a node in a panel page using node_view. I set up my own twig so I can add the links to Amazon mainly because that's how I did it on D7. I guess if I was better, I could do the same thing using a custom module, but I haven't got that far yet. All I'm basically doing is generating a link to Amazon that adds the book ISBN number to the link. 
The link works fine if I don't use panels node_view and leave it as a node, and I add a custom node type twig.

Comment: Any solution for this?  Even I am facing the same issue